# Awaiting reactions and Reaction role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Awaiting reactions in a specific channel whatever you say and Reaction role on a specific message.

I have a problem with these two.

I can't find a solution and nothing I could find from the internet worked.

I am currently using **Discord.js  v12.2.0** .

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {

  if (reaction.id === "<The ID of the Reaction>") {

    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'ROLE');

    if (message.channel.name !== 'CHANNEL') {

      message.reply(':x: You must go to the channel #CHANNEL');

    } else {

      message.member.addRole(role.id);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please give us the code you tried to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you demand of the community that something must work on "Discord.js 12.2.0" you need to show us some effort, what have you tried, and why you think it isn't working. To show us, we need your code and your log files.

Comment: I actually got frustrated and just scrapped everything that I tried, but I have an example from the internet (edited to post)

Comment: And suddenly My role.js stopped working...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line :

```js
message.member.addRole(role.id); }
```

To this :

```js
message.member.roles.add(role.id);
```

Hope this helps :3

Comment: I did it, forgot to edit it to this :D
But I'm so confused, my role giving command worked today normally I haven't even touched it but now it don't work
Everything is falling apart

Comment: no nothing... 
if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Sinulta puuttuu Rooli! (!rooli [PELI] - Pelien roolit saat !roolit komennolla!)')

I have this line so if someone says just !role it says you did not include a second argument. But even when I do like !role bf it says I did not include a second arg. It worked fine like 5hours ago

Comment: Maybe replace `args[1]` with `args[0]` ?

Comment: Why? I have to check the second arg not the first?